# Android Application Close Connection in Background Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I have an android application.
It opens an internet connection to a server on another machine.
The server sends regular status updates back to the android application
The application has multiple activities and must pass over the same open connection between each activity.

Having a custom Application object which holds the connection fits this scenario very well

BUT: When my application exits I want to close the connection, terminate the threads and stop receiving these updates from the server.
However I have read article after article explaining that Android apps don't exit and it is impossible to get a terminate event/message/signal.

How does anyone ever close a connection in an Android application?
How do I stop my threads and stop wasting battery?

Comment: Have you read about the android application lifecycle? There are hooks with the Android OS calls when your application goes to the background or pauses or is removed by the OS. Can't you do something to close the connection during these phases? Check this article: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: Is the connection running in the background as a Service or an AsynchTask?

Comment: No the connection isn't running in the background. In the Application Object I start a thread. I want a stop activity for the application to stop it. I can't use activity lifecycle because activities stop and terminate all the time and I don't want to disconnect everytime the activity changes

Comment: I am currently working on a solution to this problem that uses a Binding Service. Basically I will create a binding service object that:
-On first bind calls service start
-Counts all bindings
-If binding count reaches 0 waits 2 minutes then closes the connection

It seems like a long way round just to get a simple exit notification but I will test it and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

The method I have found to achieve this is to create a service that counts bindings to itself. I then make each activity bind to the service.
If the service notices that it has 0 bindings it waits a certain amount of time and then terminates.

I have fully documented my approach here:
https://code.metcarob.com/node/201

I am not completely happy with it but it is the best solution I can find.

Comment: The link is broken